# How to make a UI element draggable ony on Y axis in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, user-interface, unity-game-engine

So, I am making an android app about some locations in my city. In my UI I have background, title, description and a selector tab, that should be dragged out and dragged back down whenever user wants it to. Here is an example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfgK8.jpg

The problem is - I don't really know how to make an event that checks when the object is being dragged in +Y or -Y axis and dragg's it to the fingers position. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event trigger to UI panel
1. UI panel, add component -> Event -> Event Trigger 
2. Add new event type Drag and add the function on it

```
public void onDragPanel()
{
    if (!_isDrag)
    {
        _isDrag = true;


        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") > 0 )
           //Move up

        else if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") < 0 )
           //Move down

    }

}
```

and for the up/down movement, you can use animation with two animation states or you can use UITWEEN from asset store. 
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/ui-tween-38583

Let me know if you have any further queries.

Good luck! 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have never used the Event Trigger, so thank you for bringing it up. But I have a problem with implementing the function:
1. Where is the _isFrag var declared (or should it be declared manually?)
2. Shouldn't the Mouse X be Mouse Y?

Right now, I have added Debug.Log() functions under every if statement, but it seems that the function does not react to swiping. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: _isDrag should be defined manually by you. it depends on your logic, i am using _isDrag, so copied the code.

Comment: else if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") < 0 ) yes it is Mouse Y, I am sorry for the type

Comment: You have to add function to the event trigger, I have edited the post and added the screenshot of the event trigger component.